# Endless loop of Chimera scans with failure

Tags: security-review, isv, security-scanner, chimera-security-scanner

Today I started a `Chimera` scan from https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/chimera__chimera_portal to scan an external API we use in an ISV app which is going into `Security Review` soon.

Instead of having results after a short time the Scans send a result email pointing to a page which says the scan has failed with this message:

> Unfortunately, one or more of our scanners were unable to successfully
>   complete a scan of the target you provided. This may be due to a
>   Chimera-related technical fault, an inability of our servers to
>   communicate with yours, or a job timeout due to the size of your
>   target.
>
> We recommend that you run a manual ZAP scan against your target and
>   utilize those results in addition to any results provided below. Rest
>   assured that our technical team has been notified and will
>   investigate.

And the scans are restarted over and over again. The scans are directed to a URL of the form `https://demoapi.customer.de/api` with given Username and Password. The token was placed in the root folder of this server so it will be found when calling `https://demoapi.customer.de/` and `https://demoapi.customer.de/api`.

[image]

How can I stop them and how can I fix them? I don't want to use the complicated **ZAP** tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chimera token was in the correct directory but could not be accessed. As soon as we changed the server settings Chimera ran and ended all its scan runs.

I still think that it is an error on the Chimera side to restart new scans in case of such an error.